# Flutter 'ChipsInputState' is missing implementations for these members: - TextInputClient.performPrivateCommand

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I am just stuck on this error. Changing channel introduce new errors. Can anyone please help me with this error. I have just wasted a whole day on this.

Using

```
flutter_form_builder: ^3.14.0-alpha.1
```

Error:-

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_chips_input-1.9.1/lib/src/chips_input.dart:88:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ChipsInputState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextInputClient.performPrivateCommand
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ChipsInputState<T> extends State<ChipsInput<T>>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:813:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.performPrivateCommand' is defined here.
  void performPrivateCommand(String action, Map<String, dynamic> data);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

flutter version:

```
Channel dev, 1.22.0-1.0.pre
```

Comment: please, use the stable channel flutter and check if the error still persists

Comment: already tried. didn't work.

Comment: Use the stable channel flutter and use the latest stable versions of flutter_form_builder which is version 3.13.3